# Изменить и фон, и картинку при наведении мыши на элемент

Tags: html, css, hover, background, img

Как при наведении на картинку, у которой круглый background c цветом, сделать изменение цвета и фона, и самой картинки (иконки) одновременно?

```css
.menu li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 53px;
    height: 53px;
    background-color: #030303;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.menu_link img{
    padding: 14px 14px 14px 14px;
}

.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu_item">
            <a href="#" class="menu_link"><img src="img/apple.png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Должно быть вот так:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам пример с Font-Awesome

```css
body{
  background:url(https://st.depositphotos.com/1986597/2352/i/950/depositphotos_23525721-stock-photo-beige-brick-background.jpg) no-repeat center/cover;
}
.circle{
  display:inline-block;
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  line-height:35px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#444;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#fff;
  opacity:.55;
}
.circle:hover{
  transition:all .3s ease;
  background-color:#2ecc71;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="circle"><i class="fa fa-android"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="circle"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="circle"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i></a>
```

Comment: Ну или при помощи fontawesome.

Comment: Спрайты - зло, размерозависимые и некрасиво анимируются )

Comment: Ну как бы, если нету таких картинок- тогда только так, или же делать шрифтовые иконки при помощи онлайн-генераторов.

Answer (score 1):

Если это `<img src="img/apple.png" alt="">` работает как задний фон то лучше использовать `backgroung-image` и растянуть пустую ссылку `<a>` на всю строчку `<li>`

Comment: Тогда будет легче изменять картинку.

Comment: там три картинки, я для примера написал код одной. не совсем понял, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменять картинку на другую, то есть картинке невозможно задать цвет через свойство color, дайте кнопке background-image() и при наведении на нее просто меняйте на другую картинку. Также рекомендую поработать с SVG. Есть еще библиотекa Font Awesome(иконки в шрифтах).

Comment: тобишь нужно создать каждой картинке отдельный класс, и просто при наведении менять на такую же, только белую, без прозрачности?

Comment: Да, именно, самый простой способ - это использовать background-image, при наведении менять url указанный в этом свойстве

Answer (score 0):

Сделать задуманое можно при помощи спрайтов картинок (иконок) + свойствами CSS: `background: url('img/icons-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0;` & `background-position: 0px 0px;`